# MySQL PHP - variable for distinct value output

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the query below to count the amount of records with distinct values in the "Period" column. The Period column contains either "Breakfast", "Lunch" or "Dinner", and the output of the formula is grouped by monthly columns and then one row for each distinct value:

Ttl. Feedback : Breakfast: XXX

Ttl. Feedback : Lunch: XXX

Ttl. Feedback : Dinner: XXX

Now, what I would need is a variable for each total number (see $mydata['total'] that is returned for Breakfast, Lunch and Dinner. The current variable only returns the total for each distinct value, and doesnt let me specifically address an individual period score.

```
    <?
    $whereParts = array();
    if ($property) {
        $whereParts[] = "Holidex = '$property' ";
    } 

    $whereParts = array();
    if ($outlet) {
        $whereParts[] = "Outlet = '$outlet' ";
    } 

    if ($pickyear) {
        $whereParts[] = "YEAR(Date) = '$pickyear' ";
    } 

    $sql = ("select distinct period from FB_Feedback_Card_Data");

    //BUILD THE FINAL QUERY
    if (count($whereParts) > 0) {
        $sql .= " WHERE " . implode('AND ', $whereParts);
    } 
    //count($whereParts) > 0

    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die('<p>Query to get case Period data from FB_Feedback_Card_Data table failed:' . mysql_error() . '</p>');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        $period = $row[0];
        //echo "$status <br>";
        $mydata = stats("period", "$period", "$property", "$outlet", "$pickyear",$mysqli);

    ?>

<tr>
    <td class="result_desc"><?echo "Ttl. Feedback : $period";?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['a']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['b']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['c']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['d']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['e']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['f']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['g']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['h']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['i']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['j']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['k']; ?></td>
    <td class="result"><? echo $mydata['l']; ?></td>
    <td class="result_ytd"><strong><? echo $mydata['total']; ?></strong></td>
</tr>

<?
// end total status stats
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `DISTINCT` for that, you need `GROUP BY`, which will put all entries with the same value on the same record, and then you only need to count each of them:

`SELECT period, count(period) as period_count FROM FB_Feedback_Card_Data WHERE ... GROUP BY period`

Comment: but how do I get the output for each distinct period into a variable? do I do this with $row[0], $row[1], etc?

Comment: @Armitage2k I edited the query a bit so its easier to get the values from the array. You would do `$periodName = $row['period']; $count = $row['period_count'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [array_sum](http://php.net/array_sum) With this you get the sum from the $mydata variable.

```
<td class="result_ytd"><strong><?= array_sum($mydata); ?></strong></td>
```

The only thing is, that there must not be any other values in the array, but I think that this is the case here.